# How to search in the Maps app?

Tags: windows-8

There seems to be no search bar in the Maps app. Even right-clicking brings up a menu without a search option. How do I search for locations in the Maps app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To search on Maps:

1. Bring up the [Charms bar](https://superuser.com/questions/493928/what-is-the-charms-bar) by either swiping in from the right of your screen or moving to the top-right or bottom-right corner of your screen (or pressing <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>) then select the Search option:

   [image]
2. Enter your search into the Search box provided and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>:

   [image]
3. Additional results can be found using the Search results button that appears in the top left after returning to the map:

   [image]
4. Clicking this brings up the additional results and refining option:

   [image]

Comment: or hitting win-c. Keyboard shortcuts are, ironically the mouse-user's salvation ;p

Answer (score 0):

Move the cursor to top-right corner or press <kbd>Win</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>.

There is a *Search* option on it.